# Page or Screen Authorization in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

Is it possible to allow users to access a specific page in Alfresco Share? Which user or user group can access to which page for example.

Comment: Would you want this page to also show them information on nodes they normally wouldn't be allowed to see?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, unless you can map your users to the fixed set of (site independent) roles (none, guest, user, admin) baked into spring surf.

These roles are wired into various classes (i.e. `org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.PageView`,`org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.User`,`org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Description`).

If you can map your users to these roles, just set the authentication value accordingly in the pages xml descriptor.

For example:
To see the document-library, share requires you to be logged in, and hence, in `site-data/pages/documentlibrary.xml` it reads `<authentication>user</authentication>`.

If you cannot map your users in this way, things can get a bit messy.